# Hyperlink to a cell reference in the same work book using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

Can I use the formula `HYPERLINK` to link to a place within the same workbook.

I can use it to open another document but I want to just move between sheets.

So in cell `A1` on sheet 1 I would want something like

```
=HYPERLINK('Sheet!2A1' , "link")
```

And then ideally, I could use :
`=HYPERLINK(C1, "link"),` 
Here `C1` would contain the location of where I want the hyperlink to go to. May need to use `INDIRECT` possibly.

I do not want to use the conventional way of inserting a hyperlink using `CTRL` + `K`, as this means I cannot make it dynamic by changing the location in `C1`.

So, how can I use `HYPERLINK` to get to a place in the same workbook ?

Answer (score 2):

This was actually quite easy, for anyone else interested you just need to use a hashtag, see examples below:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A1", "link")
```

And to create a dynamic version using a cell value as the link location:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"& C1 &"'!A1","Link")
```

Using `C1` as the dynamic cell

You could even get real creative, and use a cell from the new sheet name, so if the sheet name changes the hyperlink changes with it:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"& MID(CELL("filename",'Sheet2'!A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",'Sheet2'!A1))+1,255) &"'!A1","Link")
```